# SQLite - build library from source or include source directly into my projet

Tags: c++, sqlite

I want to use SQLite. In almost every tutorial I have found, they build dll or static lib from SQLite source and then use .h and this lib. That is OK, however, what if I take directly source from SQLite and put it into my project? The behaviour should be the same, right? Or is there any advantage from building it as a "standalone" library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can directly put the source in the project, but I think there're at least the following advantages to use it as a library:

1. You don't need to compile the sqlite3.c when building your project (but still need linking).
2. You can easily upgrade the library implementation by dll without recompiling the binaries, given the interfaces are unchanged.
3. It is cleaner to make it as a dependency rather than a part of your project.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of using the SQLite library is to drop the [`sqlite3.c` file](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) directly in your project and to compile it together with the other source files.

Creating a static or dynamic library yourself is not useful; this would just be an additional step in your application's build system.

Using a shared library makes sense only when it already comes with the OS and you can use it without compiling it.
However, that library is not necessarily the version you want, or might not have the [compile-time options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) you need.